# How can I avoid a too small h-bar (&hbar;) showing in Firexfox?

Tags: html, firefox

On the page https://www.motionmountain.net/bet.html the character h-bar (ℏ) is much smaller than an h, and hard to read. This happens **only** with Firefox (version 87.0, on OSX), not with Opera, Chrome or Safari. How can I avoid this?

**Notes:**

The character appears a few times on the page. The first time is at the end of part 1 of the proposed physics bet.

The font used is a Google font.

I also filed a Firefox bug report. What can I do in the meantime?

Note that I just have a usual Firefox. I am a simple user, and did not change anything to the downloaded version. The Firefox of Stephen (below) has no such problem.

**Details:**

A. Here is a screen shot from my Firefox on OSX:

[image]

B. Here is a second screen shot of this stackexchange question (an older version), which uses other fonts, from my Firefox on OSX:

[image]

C. Here is a third screen shot from Chrome, on OSX, that shows no such problem:

[image]

All screen shots differ from the screenshot linked in the comment.

Comment: I use Firefox and it looks fine to me.  Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MftI2.png  Are you sure that character is actually included in the Google font you are trying to use as opposed to making the browser fall back to a system font of its choice for that character?

Comment: No, I am not sure about anything, especially after I saw your correct screen shot ... But it worked for so many years in the past. I added two screen shots.

Comment: [Good webfont for mathematical symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325233/good-webfont-for-mathematical-symbols) on [so] led me to this link where you can test Google fonts with specific characters: https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=the%20character%20h-bar%20(%E2%84%8F)%20&preview.text_type=custom

Answer (score 3):

So far, I found only two solutions:

(1) Use ħ instead of ℏ  -  i.e., `&#295;` instead of `&hbar;`

The Firefox development team is working on an improvement as well.

(2) Another option is to use:

```
<span style="font-size-adjust:0.54">&hbar;</span>
```

which yields the correct size.

Answer (score 2):

Your page appears to use the Google web fonts "Open Sans" and "Crimson Text".  Neither of those fonts has a glyph for `ℏ` as tested by [Google's tool](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=the%20character%20h-bar%20(%E2%84%8F)%20&preview.text_type=custom):

[image: Open Sans Google font test for ℏ]

[image: Crimson Bar Google font test for ℏ]

There are a couple Google fonts that support the `ℏ` character.  Scrolling through I see "Noto" (several serif and sans-serif variants) and "Arimo".  If you want this character to display consistently across all browsers and devices you need to use a font that contains a glyph for it.

Comment: Stephen, thank you for all your information. The mistake must be another, because I have switched to Noto Sans and I still have the problem. It must be something simple that I am not seeing. But I have no strange settings in Firefox, and have checked everything. Some oversight somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if has anything to do with it, but Firefox's dev tools say that there is still an active CSS `font` declaration inherited from the `<body>` for that element: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wWZp.png